# How to make a Django application send money to its users using PayPal

Tags: python, django, web-applications, paypal, django-paypal

I have a Django app for online cockfights. Users can bet if their accounts on the site have balance. They do that by first buying a digital product "Online Sabong Cash-In" through PayPal. The money is sent to the website's PayPal business account. I believe, this kind of transaction is called ***user-to-website transaction***, and I've made this work using **django-paypal** library. I've followed this tutorial for that simple transaction: https://overiq.com/django-paypal-integration-with-django-paypal/ .

Now, I want to give the website the feature where users can ***cash-out*** or like withdraw their money if they want. I want to have the ***website-to-user transaction***. How can I do that, please? I've searched on Google a lot and all I see are articles for ***user-to-website transaction***. I've found one way but I don't know how to do it using **django-paypal** library:https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/.

Comment: I am not sure but currently there is no API call for withdrawing money from paypal to bank account according to this [community post](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/NVP-SOAP-APIs/PayPal-API-to-withdraw-funds-from-PayPal-to-Bank-account/m-p/2142031/highlight/true#M2207)

Comment: That's not the question though -- the question is about sending money to a PayPal account. No bank is necessary for an account to receive money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal has a Payouts API, which you can [request access](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites#get-access-to-paypal-payouts) to. However, only certain use cases will be approved.

([There is a way](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/) to facilitate ***user-to-user*** transactions by setting a `payee` object for the checkout, but that's not what you're asking in the question)